# Multiple posts with fixed order position

Tags: posts

I have a scenario where I need to account for promo posts/ads within a category. For example, say I have a category called "featured", when I click through to this category, posts #2, #6 and #8 will display posts from the "Promo" category, while the rest of the "featured" posts would continue to render as normal.

My thinking was to create a "Promo" category, and add a custom field of "sequence" to the posts within this category. Then, during the rendering of the featured loop check the position in the loop, check to see whether a post of Promo with sequence position exists, and display this, somehow - I'm not sure how.

What would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence field would determine where the promo post appears (position 2, 6, 8)?

Anyway, I'd do it (and actually have done it) that way and would do it like that again. No other, more elegant way that comes to my mind.